# What happens when an exception occurs in a module initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I have a module, and in this module I initialize some variables as soon as the module is imported.

my_mobule.py:

```
def _build_service():
    # ...do some stuffs

_service = _build_service()
```

In this case, what will happen if the `_build_service` method raises an exception? And how my module can recover from an exception and try to invoke the `_build_service` again?

Thank you guys.

Comment: It seems like the first step, before posting this question, is to make it raise an exception and see what happens.

Comment: You should handle the exception and provide some default value or use invariants...

Comment: @larsks I did that, that's why I'm asking here. Because I saw the exception, but I don't know with the python will try to import this module ever again or not, since my app keeps running. That's my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty similar to the behaviour should you call a function which raises an exception - if you don't handle the exception in the module itself, then it will be simply bump up the stack to whoever imported your module.

That would look like this:

```
>>> import my_mobule  # sic
UhohError: something went wrong
```

If you have an opportunity to handle it in the module, you could do it like so:

```
try:
    _service = _build_service()
except UhohError:
    # your handling code here
```